# Update large table with exception hadling

Tags: postgresql, exception

I've got a big table "Foo" with millions rows, for simplicity let table have 3 columns: "@ID" of type bigint, "hs_params" of type text in HSTORE format and "number" of type int. I need to write "number" to "hs_params" as "NUMBER" (or renew, if it already exist). The problem is that in some records "hs_params" is not valid HSTORE and it throws an exception "internal_error" (code XX000) when trying to cast it. I tried to find out the "@ID"s of the rows where the incorrect parameters are stored, using the code below, but it running for a 2 hours and crash when i lost connection with the database, so it looks like query should not just handling an exception, but also be as much quick as possible.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   r record;
   hs hstore;
BEGIN
FOR r IN SELECT * FROM "Foo"
LOOP
    BEGIN
        hs = r."hs_params"::hstore;
    EXCEPTION WHEN internal_error THEN
        raise notice 'ERROR on % with hs text %', r."@ID", r."hs_params";
    END;
END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: That is slow, because savepoints are, but it is the best way to do this. If it crashes, that's a PostgreSQL bug you should report. But first make sure that you are running the latest point release of a supported version.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Well, perhaps "crash" is not completely right word here, because i just lost connection with db with the message about it. The sad story here is that i don't get any data even after 2 hours of running. Can you tell me if you know: i used pg_admin3 and asked to save query results to file, it is possible that i don't get any data because it's firstly trying to execute whole query and then save all to file, not write the message immediately as it appears?

Comment: Hard to say - I use `psql`. Try with that. There might also be a problem with toi many savepoints in one transaction. You could split the job into smaller batches.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ok, how should i transform existing code to achieve table updating, not just selecting?

Comment: You can use an explicit cursor (see the PL/pgSQL documentation) and `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF` to modify the data row by row. But you should try to figure out more about the "internal error". What is the exact error message?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
`ERROR:  Unexpected end of string
********** Error **********`
`ERROR: Unexpected end of string
SQL state: XX000`

Comment: Well, that's kind of expected. Strange that it has been made an "internal error". I'm wondering about the "crash". Anything in the server log? A memory context dump?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe As i say before, "crash" is not right word here: i just lost connection with database, i don't think this is becuase of the query executing. Maybe system or admin just kill the proccess, cuase it's working too long. When i use simple `SELECT` with cast to hstore it throw exactly this exception after 15 minutes of working. So i don't think you should worry about "crash".